# Django Wizard Form and other view in one page

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I'm trying to show a wizard form and a table (that is generated by this form and can be seen in every step) in one page. Is it possible?

I have tried:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [url('', GroupsWizard.as_view(form_list), name = 'index'),]
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    groups_render = Groups.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'groups_render' : groups_render})

class GroupsWizard(SessionWizardView):

    def get_template_names(self):
        return 'index.html'

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        data = {k: v for form in form_list for k, v in form.cleaned_data.items()}
        instance = Groups.objects.create(**data)
        return render(self.request, 'done.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })
```

index.html

```
<div>
  {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
      {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<div>
{{ groups_render }}
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found it,

I used get_context_data function in views.py:

```
class GroupsWizard(SessionWizardView):

    def get_template_names(self):
        return 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(GroupsWizard, self).get_context_data(form = form, **kwargs)
        context_data = Groups.objects.all()
        context.update({'context_data': context_data})
        return context

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        data = {k: v for form in form_list for k, v in form.cleaned_data.items()}
        instance = Groups.objects.create(**data)
        return render(self.request, 'done.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })
```